# How can i pull one piece of data from a wikipedia table with beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, api, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

So i'm trying to get how many cases of coronavirus are currently confirmed in Colombia for a website. I only need to show the number of cases and i'm using bs4. However, i know basic stuff about programming and i don't know python. here's what i've got

```
import bs4

import requests

response = requests.get("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandemia_de_enfermedad_por_coronavirus_de_2020_en_Colombia")

if response is not None:
    html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    title = html.select(".infobox")[0].text
    paragraphs = html.select("tr")
    #for para in paragraphs:
        #print (para.text)

    mylist = soup.find_all('td')
    print(mylist.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

> *I'm trying to get how many cases of coronavirus are currently
>   confirmed in Colombia*

There are many [api's](https://github.com/pomber/covid19) with real time data available and you don't need to scrape Wikipedia for this information. Here's a `python` example:

```
import requests

j = requests.get("https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json").json()
# j['Colombia'] # full `timeseries` that you can import in pandas

# to get latest available date, use [-1]:
confirmed = j['Colombia'][-1]['confirmed']
deaths = j['Colombia'][-1]['deaths']
recovered = j['Colombia'][-1]['recovered']
# {'date': '2020-4-24', 'confirmed': 4881, 'deaths': 225, 'recovered': 1003}
```

---

As a side note, I call this *virus* the [con](https://www.google.com/search?q=con)vid19

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example of using an API instead of **scraping** Wikipedia, in this case the free [covid19 API](https://covid19api.com):

```
import requests

class Covid19ApiHelper:
    URL_API = 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary'

    def __init__(self):
        self._global_info = None
        self._countries = None

    def refresh(self):
        """Request data from the API and saves it"""
        response = requests.get(self.URL_API)
        data = response.json()

        self._global_info = data['Global']   
        self._countries = {item['CountryCode']: item for item in data['Countries']}

    def get_global_info(self):
        return self._global_info

    def get_country_info(self, countryCode):
        """Returns the information by country using the standard two digit country code"""
        return self._countries[countryCode]

if __name__=='__main__':
    covid_helper = Covid19ApiHelper()
    covid_helper.refresh()

    print(covid_helper.get_global_info())
    print(covid_helper.get_country_info('CO'))
```

Output Global:

```
{'NewConfirmed': 86850, 'TotalConfirmed': 2894581, 'NewDeaths': 5839, 'TotalDeaths': 202795, 'NewRecovered': 27616, 'TotalRecovered': 815948}
```

Output Colombia:

```
{'Country': 'Colombia', 'CountryCode': 'CO', 'Slug': 'colombia', 'NewConfirmed': 261, 'TotalConfirmed': 5142, 'NewDeaths': 8, 'TotalDeaths': 233, 'NewRecovered': 
64, 'TotalRecovered': 1067, 'Date': '2020-04-26T09:16:56Z'}
```

Source of data: https://covid19api.com/#details

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate you take the time to answer my question, thanks this wasn't a requirement but i wanted to learn how it was possible to do this with python, it works perfectly!